# python Unicode decode error when accessing records of OrderedDict

Tags: python, unicode, ordereddictionary

using python 3.5.2 on windows (32), I'm reading a DBF file which returns me an OrderedDict.

```
from dbfread import DBF
Table = DBF('FME.DBF')
for record in Table:
   print(record)
```

When accessing the first record all is ok until I reach a record which contains diacritics:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getdbe.py", line 3, in <module>
    for record in Table:
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 311, in _iter_records
    for field in self.fields]
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 311, in <listcomp>
    for field in self.fields]
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 75, in parse
    return func(field, data)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 83, in parseC
    return decode_text(data.rstrip(b'\0 '), self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Even if I don't print the record I still have the problem.

Any idea ?

Comment: https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#character-encodings, try passing `DBF(...)` the correct encoding.

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @Harrison: I highly doubt it, DBF is not a format where I'd expect to see UTF-8 encoded data. Where does the OP even mention UTF-8 however?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbfread` failed to detect the correct encoding from your DBF file. From the [*Character Encodings* section of the documentation](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#character-encodings):

> `dbfread` will try to detect the character encoding (code page) used in the file by looking at the `language_driver` byte. **If this fails it reverts to ASCII**. You can override this by passing `encoding='my-encoding'`.

Emphasis mine.

You'll have to pass in an explicit encoding; this will invariably be a Windows codepage. Take a look at the [supported codecs in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings); you'll have to use one that starts with `cp` here. If you don't know what codepage to you you'll have some trial-and-error work to do. Note that some codepages overlap in characters, so even if a codepage appears to produce legible results, you may want to continue searching and trying out different records in your data file to see what fits best.

Comment: That's the right answer. I had problem finding the right encoding, so I looked the first encountered diacritic i.e. **"é"** and searched which encoding correspond to **x82**, I found it was cp850 (MS-DOS).

Comment: @SDufour: there are [11 codepages where `é` is encoded as 0x82](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/codepage_support.htm). You could possibly narrow that down further with more codepoints.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had time to look at it.

Comment: One could image a program which will read throught a file and instead of throwing exceptions would show you the surrounding words and ask you which character is expected, removing all codepages that aren't matching. Does it look possible ?

Comment: @SDufour: yes, that's something that is possible, given that the number of codecs here is limited to 1-byte encodings which all are supersets of ASCII.